# Why is async method in static constructor causing deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, deadlock, nlog

This is the minimum (and simplified) repro of the real code that I was investigating due to it causing a dead lock. The `OuterClass` has some nested classes, which get initialize (and load some data) with initialization of the outer class. It's important that the data is available once the object is initialized.

```cs
public class OuterClass
{   
    static ILogger Log = LogManager.GetLogger("OuterClass");

    private static InnerClass _innerClass;
    public static OuterClass Instance { get; private set; }

    private OuterClass()
    {
        Log.Debug("Constructor called");
        _innerClass = new InnerClass();
    }

    static OuterClass()
    {
        Instance = new OuterClass();
    }

    public class InnerClass
    {
        // using it's own logger, it will not dead lock
        //static ILogger Log = LogManager.GetLogger("InnerClass");

        private String _data;
        public InnerClass()
        {
            LoadOrUpdateDataAsync().Wait(); // will make the second Log.Debug call dead lock
            //_ = LoadOrUpdateDataAsync(); // will work
        }

        public async Task LoadOrUpdateDataAsync()
        {
            Log.Debug("This works");

            _data = await DataClass.GetDataAsync("https://someusefulapi.com/api/xyz");

            Log.Debug("If you see this, it did not block"); // this line blocks
        }
    }
}

public static class DataClass
{
    static ILogger Log = LogManager.GetLogger("DataClass");
    public static async Task<string> GetDataAsync(string uri)
    {
        // just example code, HttpClient should not be in a using block
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var data = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
            Log.Debug("Data loaded from {0}", uri);
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Console output from above code:

```txt
Time         Logger  Thread-Id   Message
16:47:39 OuterClass          1   Constructor called
16:47:39 OuterClass          1   This works
16:47:40  DataClass          7   Data loaded from https://someusefulapi.com/api/xyz
```

The second Log `Log.Debug("If you see this...");` blocks - the application hangs. I am guessing that it hangs at this point, because the `LoadOrUpdateDataAsync().Wait();` call is blocking the `Logger` which is shared by the `OuterClass` and `InnerClass`. The `await DataClass.GetDataAsync(...)` is executed by a different thread (different thread id). So when the await completes, the method resumes on the "new" thread, but the Logger is blocked by the main thread. Or should the code actually work, meaning it's an NLog issue?

The NLog configuration is minimalistic. I tried versions NLog 4.7.15 and 5.0.4 - which behave identical. The `async="true"` option, also makes no difference. It's .Net Framework 4.7.2.

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <targets async="true">
        <target name="console" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} ${pad:padCharacter= :padding=10:fixedLength=True:inner=${logger}} ${mdlc:item=ProcessDescriptorId}   ${threadid}   ${message} ${exception:format=tostring} ${exception:format=stacktrace}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

This code really only hangs when `LoadOrUpdateDataAsync()` is called from the constructor. Putting the call to an `Init()`function and calling it with `OuterClass.Instance.Init();` will not block.

Also, using the discard operator `_ = LoadOrUpdateDataAsync();` will work. But it's not an option, because the main Thread will continue, without having the confidence that the data is really loaded.

Console output with `_ = LoadOrUpdateDataAsync();`:

```txt
Time         Logger    Thread-Id   Message
16:49:54 OuterClass            1   Constructor called
16:49:54 OuterClass            1   This works
16:49:55  DataClass            9   Data loaded from https://someusefulapi.com/api/xyz
16:49:55 OuterClass            9   If you see this, it did not block
```

Also using an own Logger in the `InnerClass` will work (with the `.Wait()` call).

Console output with own Logger in `InnerClass` and `LoadOrUpdateDataAsync().Wait();`:

```txt
Time         Logger    Thread-Id   Message
16:52:51 OuterClass            1   Constructor called
16:52:51 InnerClass            1   This works
16:52:52  DataClass            8   Data loaded from https://someusefulapi.com/api/xyz
16:52:52 InnerClass            8   If you see this, it did not block
```

From the 2 last examples it is clear that the second `Log.Debug()` runs on a different thread than the first one.

I am aware that calling async functions from constructors is suboptimal and that there are better ways to do it - like using the Factory Pattern as described in this
[blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) by [Stephen Cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)

I am primarilly interested in why this codes blocks and wish to understand what is technically going on here. Are my assumptions correct or am I on the wrong path?

Second, is the above mentioned Factory Pattern the "correct" way to solve it, or is there an  even better approach?

Comment: Are you sure the posted code reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Maddin I wasn't able to reproduce it here https://dotnetfiddle.net/rUyQWp

Comment: The problem is the `static OuterClass()` constructor that suddenly waits for Async-Call and the `InnerClass` must wait for `OuterClass`-static-members to be fully initialized (Ex. the static Logger of `OuterClass`). You should change `static OuterClass Instance`-property to be implemented using `Lazy<OuterClass>`.

Comment: @StephenCleary I was able to repro on Windows machine with .NET 6 in debug mode (have not tried anything else).

Comment: @StephenCleary the code reproduces the problem. I'm on a Windows maschine; it's a console app in VS 2022 with .Net Framework 4.7.2. Copied the code 1:1. I didn't try it with dotnetfiddle, to be honest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't pinpoint exact code which leads to the described behavior because this will require going down the rabbit hole of CLR implementation (playing with `dotnet-dump analyze` seems to result in the unmanaged transition in the continuation invocation after `_data = await ...`) but the reason for such behaviour is not the NLog per se but the fact that runtime guarantees that static constructor will be executed only once and in your code basically the following happens:

1. `OuterClass` static ctor starts invocation
2. `InnerClass` ctor is called
3. `InnerClass` ctor blocks on `LoadOrUpdateDataAsync` (and blocks the thread which handles the ctor)
4. `LoadOrUpdateDataAsync` waits for IO completion
5. After IO completion `LoadOrUpdateDataAsync` tries to access something from `OuterClass` from another thread but `OuterClass` static construction has not finished, so it blocks until the construction is finished leading to deadlock because static ctor waits for `LoadOrUpdateDataAsync`.

The repro can be simplified to:

```cs
public class OuterClass
{   
    // ...

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here Outer");
    }

    public class InnerClass
    {
        private String _data;
        public InnerClass()
        {
            LoadOrUpdateDataAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();//.Wait();
        }

        public async Task LoadOrUpdateDataAsync()
        {
            _data = await DataClass.GetDataAsync("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json").ConfigureAwait(false);
            Console.WriteLine("Here Inner"); // works
            OuterClass.DoSomething(); // blocks
        }
    }
}
```

This actually is described in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors#:%7E:text=The%20runtime%20calls,Parallel%20LINQ%20queries):

> The runtime calls a static constructor no more than once in a single application domain. That call is made in a locked region based on the specific type of the class. No additional locking mechanisms are needed in the body of a static constructor. To avoid the risk of deadlocks, don't block the current thread in static constructors and initializers. For example, don't wait on tasks, threads, wait handles or events, don't acquire locks, and don't execute blocking parallel operations such as parallel loops, `Parallel.Invoke` and Parallel LINQ queries.